# create a msi installer

Tags: python-2.7, wix

Visual studio 2010 did not help me to build a deployment project to create a msi installer using msbuild.
I'm asked to write a python script which automatically builds and creates a msi installer. I came up with a solution of using wix tool.But, I have no idea about it.Please suggest me an idea for it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!. Since i have no idea about xml coding i thought of asking here.

Comment: So you must learn it. If it is a piece of code that doesn't work that you think should then you can ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Visual Studio 2010 lets you create MSI project you can look here:
   [image]

however since .vdproj files are no longer supported in VS2012 i suggest you learn how to use WIX installer.
2. If you want to learn how to use WIX installer i suggest you google for Wix Installer Tutorial before asking here:
http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/

3.If you need to learn about XML 
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I will go through wix installer.