# python, making a windows msi installer from a zip file

Tags: python, windows-installer

I used [Esky](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/esky) to make a frozen version of my app but the output is a zip file which is supposed to be extracted to work. What library makes a nice installer (uninstaller) that just asks for a folder and unzip it in there?

Also, a mac solution for the exact same problem would be nice too. Output of Esky is a zip file no matter what OS you use.

Comment: Some zip file utilities like WinZip and 7-Zip have the ability to create self-extracting zip files that can be run on Windows. You could use Esky to create the zip, then the utility to turn it into a self-extracting one.

Comment: [InfoZip](http://www.info-zip.org/pub/infozip/) is another one, and it looks like it supports many operating systems.

Comment: I was hoping to find something nicer. self-extracting files look kind of sketchy, i think?

Comment: Any installer will involve an executable. You could create your own witten in Python and use py2exe, portable Python, or something similar to convert that into such a standalone program.

Comment: I meant I rather have normal windows installation process instead of winzip or 7z. cx_Freeze actually makes msi installer which is good but I can't use that with my already compiled zip :(

Answer (score 0):

From the comments I didn't fully understood what you were looking for so I'll give you more than 1 options:

http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/builtdist.html#creating-windows-installers

http://docs.python.org/2/library/msilib.html

Very easy way to make windows installers is using VS: [create a msi installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661444/create-a-msi-installer)

Answer (score 0):

You Could use Cx_Freeze...
You can create the .py file into an Exe so it can be excecuted on computers without Python installed.

To create the Msi you will need to do what you would to to create an exe but when you would type setup.py build in the CMD type setup.py bdist_msi build